# There is no registered service of type error in blazor.net when adding a new service

Tags: blazor

I have set up a sample [blazor.net application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-razor-components-app?view=aspnetcore-3.0) as per the Docs. After that I created a new service and hard-coded few data and trying to run the application.

But I'm receiving the following error in the console:

> There is no registered service of type `<applicationName>.App.Services.<serviceName>`

It seems the new service name need to register some where, how can I register the new service?

Comment: Also be careful if you are registering with an interface like builder.services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface, MyNewService> that you inject with the Interface type and not the concret class type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The newly created service name should be register in the `ConfigureServices` method in the `<applicationName>.App\Startup.cs` file.

For example, if the new service name is `MyNewService.cs`, it should be added as below in the `ConfigureServices` method.

Sample code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ... existing services
        services.AddSingleton<MyNewService>();
    }

    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! It works with Blazor official release. Today I am lucky when see your answer.

Comment: configured services in the Blazor WebAssembly  3.2.0 client have been moved from Startup.ConfigureServices to Program.cs builder.Services collection

Answer (score 16):

Worth noting that for Blazor WebAssembly, there is no Startup class like the one in Blazor Server. In Blazor WebAssembly we can register Services in Program.cs as below:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

    //...other services
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyNewService>();

    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
 }
```

Comment: For example, with DevExpress blazor webassembly, In Client project, file `Program.cs` , add `builder.Services.AddDevExpressBlazor();`before `await builder.Build().RunAsync();`